# When does this sum converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

When does the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{{n!n^{-p}}\over{q(q+1)...(q+n)}}$ converge? It is supposed to be solved by Gauss's test, but I get ${a_{n+1}\over a_n} = {{n+1}\over{q+n+1}} ({{n}\over{n+1}})^p$. What to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
{a_{n+1}\over a_n} = {{n+1}\over{q+n+1}} \left({{n}\over{n+1}}\right)^p
= \left( 1 - \frac qn  + O(1/n^2)\right)
\left( 1 - \frac pn  + O(1/n^2)\right)
= 1 - \frac {p+q}n  + O(1/n^2).
$$Then according to [Gauss' test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html) test there is convergence iff 
$
p+q >1
$.