# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{{n!n^{-p}}\over{q(q+1)...(q+n)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{{n!n^{-p}}\over{q(q+1)...(q+n)}}$

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730483/when-does-this-sum-converge?noredirect=1) post can you explain how first step is done?

I understand that we need to use Gauss test here but  can't understand how to get this

${{n+1}\over{q+n+1}} \left({{n}\over{n+1}}\right)^p
= \left( 1 - \frac qn  + O(1/n^2)\right)
\left( 1 - \frac pn  + O(1/n^2)\right)
 $

Comment: Please add more context. Do not hide the relevant details behind a link; explain to us what the first step was, and what you were confused about.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I edited my question,is it okay now?

Answer (score 2):

1)There is an alternative and easier way to check for convergence as we will see soon. About the operations from the post, if $p\in\mathbb{N}$, look at this:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{n+1}{q+n+1}&=&1-\frac{q}{n+q+1}\\
&=& 1 -\frac{q}{n}+\frac{q}{n}-\frac{q}{n+q+1}\\
&=& 1-\frac{q}{n} + \frac{q^2+q}{n(n+q+1)}\\
&=& 1 - \frac{q}{n}+O(1/n^2)
\end{eqnarray}
since $\frac{n^2(q^2+q)}{n(n+q+1)}\to q^2+q$ when $n\to\infty$.
For the other factor using binomial theorem we got
\begin{eqnarray}
\Bigg(\frac{n}{n+1}\Bigg)^p &=& \Bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\Bigg)^p\\
&=& 1 - \frac{p}{n+1} + \displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^p \binom{p}{k}\Bigg(-\frac{1}{n+1}\Bigg)^k\\
&=& 1-\frac{p}{n}+\frac{p}{n}- \frac{p}{n+1} + \displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^p \binom{p}{k}\Bigg(-\frac{1}{n+1}\Bigg)^k\\
&=& 1 - \frac{p}{n} + O(1/n^2)
\end{eqnarray}
since $\frac{pn^2}{n(n+1)}+n^2\sum_{k=2}^p \binom{p}{k}\Big(-\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^k\to p+\binom{p}{2}$ as $n\to\infty$. Case when $p\in\mathbb{R_+}$ is similar.

2)The alternative way for checking convergence is using the  Pringsheim's Criteria that states the following:
If $S=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ is a series with non-negative terms, we have

- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^pa_n<\infty$ and $p>1$, then $S$ is convergent.
- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^pa_n\not= 0$ and $p\le 1$, then $S$ is divergent.

Comment: $\frac{p}{n} - \frac{p}{n+1}$ this is $\frac{p}{n(n+1)}$,can you explain how you get $n^2$ in front?

Comment: $\frac{p/[n(n+1)]}{1/n^2}=\frac{n^2p}{n(n+1)}$, i do that to show that indeed $\frac{p}{n(n+1)}=O(1/n^2)$. It is just applying definition of big O notation.

Comment: For negative $p$ binomial theorem we can't use, so taylor series we need for $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: For negative p we can indeed use binomial theorem,  there is even a generalization given by Isaac Newton using Pochhammer's symbol.

Comment: If we use $(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+ \alpha x + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ we will get same right?And plug $\frac{-1}{n+1}$ for $x$

Comment: I dont know how did you get $O(1/n^2)$ when your expression does not depend on `n`, but on `x` and `\alpha`. Nevertheless, what are you trying to do is already done above.

Comment: Sorry I meant $(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+ \alpha x + O(\frac{1}{x^2})$ and for $x$ plug -$\frac{1}{n+1}$. I am interested in this way also because yet i am not sure how proof works of binomial formula for negative $p$.

Comment: If you plug $-\frac{1}{n+1}$ for x, then you will get $O((n+1)^2)$.

Comment: Is there @TomKeen more simple way doing $(\frac{n}{n+1})^p$ other than using that binomial formula?

Comment: I dont think so,  if you have a binomial, commonly you must use either binomial theorem or beurnolli inequality $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$ if $x>-1$.